PC Not Turning On via Wake-on-LAN (WOL) on Windows 11 with Intel 8th Gen NUC
I'm having an issue with Wake-on-LAN (WOL) on one of my PCs, and I'm hoping to get some guidance. Here are the details of the PC:
NUC: 8th Gen Intel NUC
OS: Windows 11 (version 22631.388)
Network driver: 12.19.2.50
GFX driver: 31.0.101.2114
What I've done so far:

BIOS Settings: Set "Wake-on-LAN from S4/S5" to "Power On - Normal Boot".

Ethernet Properties: Enabled "Wake on Magic Packet" and "Wake on Pattern Match".
Tried "Forced" and "Disabled" for "Wake on Link Settings".

Power Management: Ticked all 3 options in the "Power Management" tab.


I have other PCs where either the Windows version or the NUC generation is the same, and WOL works perfectly fine on those. However, it's not working on this specific PC.
Could this be due to a hardware issue, or is there something I'm overlooking in the configuration? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks.

How are you testing it (what tool are you using, and where are you running it)? What do you mean by "network driver"; do you mean the Ethernet driver for a specific Ethernet interface? Are the magic packet sender host and target host both on the same wired Ethernet LAN? Is it straight Ethernet between both hosts (no Wi-Fi, MoCA, or powerline; also no routers or NAT gateways in between)?

@Spiff We are having an In-house application that executes WOL command if the PC owners biometrics are successfully read. You may assume the 'true' value of the biometric application output as some sort of trigger for the WOL. For the other PCs, it works when the biometric value is true which means the trigger is not an issue. Only in this specific PC we are having the issue. By network driver, we mean the ethernet driver. Yes, all are on the same wired LAN and all the PCs are in the same subnet.
